# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS: I want to remap my Flydigi FeiZhi D1 bluetooth one-handed keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, keyboard-layout

I recently bougth a Flydigi FeiZhi D1 bluetooth one-handed keyboard. To use it for games, I need to remap the buttons.

Because Ubuntu seems to recognize that device as a gamepad,  the buttons do not do what I want. BTW I use Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

If I press "W" for example while I am typing this post, the cursor jumps to the "Search on Ask Ubuntu" input field at the top of the page.

I already tried xev to get the information on what key to press on the D1 keyboard. When I press "W" I get the following output in the terminal:

```
PropertyNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    atom 0x164 (_NET_WM_STATE), time 3088884, state PropertyNewValue

PropertyNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    atom 0x1b1 (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 3088884, state PropertyNewValue
```

I'm not even shure if that is the valid output or if it is the output for the mouse moving/button pressing to switch to the terminal.

So I guess I need something like xmodmap to remap the buttons. Unfortunately I don't have good knowledge about xmodmap or even with Ubuntu. But I’m willing to try my best! :D

I hope somone with better knowledge of hardware and Linux than me is willing to help me.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release you are using?

Comment: @Pilot6 Sorry for missing that point! Thanks for hindsighting! I use `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`

Answer (score 0):

[Antimicro](https://github.com/AntiMicro/antimicro) successfully maps buttons of gamepads and joysticks to keyboard input on Ubuntu 20.04 and is avaliable in the universe apt source.

[image]